# Is there a Monero forum?

Tags: community

I see search results for [forum.getmonero.org](https://forum.getmonero.org/) but loading any page of it gives a 404 page, and has done so for days.

Has this forum been shut down intentionally?   Is there another forum?    I know about [reddit.com/r/Monero](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/), but those threads seem very transient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a Monero forum at that address. It was seldom used, however, and the usual assholes on the web pushed a lot of spam on it. After a burst of activity when iit was launched, the only part of it that was really still used was the forum funding system, and this has since been migrated to a git based system, making the forum best shuttered to avoid people posting there and getting no reply.

Comment: That's all good. The nice thing to would be to put up a page telling the story you just did, pointing to alternatives ex. [/r/Monero](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/)

Comment: ok, thx I guess that answers my question, though I'm disappointed there isn't a real forum any longer.   oh well....

Answer (score 0):

There is a Monero Forum maintained by the Monero Space work group using the open source framework Flarum: https://forum.monero.space/